# How to combine two reports using subreports

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I've got two reports that I wish to combine into one print off. Report1 is a 2 page report and has an ID parameter, Report2 is a 1 page report and also has the same ID parameter. The ID's come from a separate query dataset1

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE firstname = 'Dave'
```

I want there to be 3 pages per id. I have tried putting two subreports into a List, where the list has a dataset linked to my SELECT query, but this displays all of the Report1's and then all of the Report2's after.

Desired output: (Report1pg1[id=1], Report1pg2[id=1], Report2pg1[id=1]), (Report1pg1[id=2], Report1pg2[id=2], Report2pg1[id=2])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure and i don't have no data tools installed in my current machine to check.
But I think the following logic will work.

Try `grouping with id in Report1` and in detail portion add `subreport` and call Report2 (assuming that you are using table)

Comment: So you're saying not to use two subreports? I have currently grouped the List `rectangle1` by id, then inside this `rectangle1` I have `subreport1` and `subreport2`. Screen: http://d.pr/i/X01k

Comment: Why do you add the `subreport2 in Report1 detail` itselft and group that by id. Do that groupng based on ID in report 1 itself and add subreport2 in that detail portion.

Comment: The only problem with that is that when I make changes to Report1, I need to also update this version with the changes. Thanks btw.